# Only since Debian 11: regular users can't write to world/group writable files under /tmp/ owned by other users, unless owner is root

Tags: debian, permissions, filesystems, tmp

**Users:**

- `root`
- `userA` - the normal owner of the file
- `userB` - the user that wants to write to the file

**The file:**

- Let's say I have a basic text file: `/tmp/file`
- Ownership: `chown userA:groupA /tmp/file`
- Permissions are group + world writable: `chmod 666 /tmp/file`

**The problem:**

- `userB` can't write to it via the world/everyone permission
- `userB` also can't even write to it when they're in the `groupA` group
- I'm only seeing this on a new Debian 11 host.

  - There's no issue on my Debian 10 hosts.

**What does work:**

- If I `chown root:root /tmp/file` - no problem

  - ...this is the weirdest part to me.  If this is some new security policy or something, then why is this allowed?
- If I move the file outside `/tmp` - no problem

**What's going on here?**

Has something changed between Debian 10 -> 11?

There's nothing non-default about my `/tmp` dir.  It's not a separate partition or anything, it's just the default subdir setup that Debian comes with.

Answer (score 0):

- So I typed my question up, and then realized that I should also try
  writing to the file as root... and was surprised that not even that
  was allowed either.

  - Perhaps that's why I didn't find much info in
    all my initial searches trying to figure this out.  Most other users tried that first I guess, so their thread titles are a bit different to what I was looking for.
  - So hopefully me still posting + answering this can help someone in the future, if they happen to use search terms like I was.
- It seems that the cause is the new default setting on `sysctl fs.protected_regular`
- I'm still a bit surprised by the fact that `userB` can write to the
  file if `root:root` owns it.  But I guess there needs to be some way to
  really allow world writable files.

  - Although it being owned by root feels like a kinda reverse way to do
    it.  I'm keen to hear if anyone has any insights into why this is
    allowed.